# Roof flashing material and thickness

Tags: roof, roofing, flashing

For residential roofs, what is the most common metal to use for step flashing and apron flashing, and what would you recommend? Is there a particular thickness I should request for step and apron flashings? I live in Mid-Atlantic region, mixed-humid climate, in climate zone 4a. I'm actually not sure what my house sheathing is except that it is plywood or OSB. I plan to use GAF HDZ shingles.