# How can I determine proper step flashing size and thickness?

Tags: roof, roofing, flashing, shingles

I plan to use GAF Timberline HDZ shingles (fiberglass asphalt) when my house is reroofed. What would be the best dimensions for the step flashing? Would a 5"x5"x8" size for step flashings be good? The shingle dimensions are 13-1/4" x 39-3/8" and exposure is 5-5/8".

Comment: All the dimensions you've just quoted are for _thickness_. The dimensions in your question are about _area_ (length x width). Your [other question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/284692/roof-flashing-material-and-thickness) is about thickness, so I presumed this one was about area only.

Comment: For a ballpark, is it unreasonable to think typical 2-story ~5000 SF house might not need >3 boxes of step flashings? (250/box, each 5x5x10" piece will overlap ~2" to cover ~3" distance) I realize sloped roof-sidewall intersections would be longer than corresponding ceiling-wall intersections so I intentionally doubled lengths of all ceiling-wall intersections under the roof-sidewall intersections to overestimate, then totaled for overestimated needed coverage distance and got 2112", which I divided by 3" per piece = 704 pieces. 704/250 per box = 2.81 boxes.

Comment: I am also interested in thickness too, I would rely on a contractor to use right method to determine # boxes. I don't want to bother them to figure that out just so I can do price comparison between standard thickness step flashing and 0.018" thick. However, I need to let them know which thickness I want before they figure out the estimate which is hard to know if I have no clue how many boxes I need. The difference between 3 vs 4 boxes of upgraded cost won't likely make a difference, but 6 boxes of upgraded might. I am hoping 3 or maybe 4 boxes would cover the roof, with a little to spare.

Comment: I was interested in answers to both questions No one answered the other one, so I figured I'd ask you here. I'd rely on a contractor determine number of boxes actually. I don't want to bother them to figure out a price comparison between standard vs 0.018" thickness, but I was supposed to let the know what I want to be included on estimate. A local roofing wholesaler who I know the contractor uses can order the 0.018". Of course they won't tell me the price difference, but I figure if it is just for 3 or 4 boxes that might be tolerable. If it is for 10 boxes, probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am *not* a professional roofer.

---

I did the flashing on my roof when I built a garage 30 years ago. I used whatever pre-formed flashing was available at my local hardware store without a second thought. There was only one option, so I used it. I don't know the dimensions nor the thickness of the material I used it was simply, "pre-bent aluminum step flashing".

I had one location leak because I didn't properly take care of the siding on the wall above the flashing, but I never had a failure of the flashing itself.

IMHO, I don't think size nor thickness will matter in the long run, so long as what you do use is properly installed.

Comment: Yeah, use two or more per shingle course if necessary. Thickness doesn't much matter as the shingles will fail first. It's almost not worth thinking about.